# Spark Structured Streaming - WAL performance degradation

Tags: performance, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

We have a spark structured streaming query that reads data from **eventhub**, does some **processing** and write data back to **eventhub**. We have **checkpointing enabled** - we store the checkpoint data in the Azure Datalake Gen2.

When we run the query, we see something weird - over time, our **query's performance (latency) slowly degrades**. When we run the query for the first time, the batch duration time is ~3 secs. After a day of run, the batch duration time is 20 secs and after 2 days, we get to a 40 secs+.. Interestingly, when we delete the checkpoint folder (or otherwisely reset the checkpoint), the latency goes back to normal (2 secs).

Looking at the query performance after 2 days of running on the same checkpoint directory, it is quite clear that it is the **write-ahead-log / "walCommit"**, which grows and after some time accounts for the majority of the processing time.

[image]

**My questions are:** what drives this behaviour - is it natural for walCommit to take longer and longer? Could it be Azure Datalake Gen2 specific? Do we even need write-ahead-logs for eventhub? What are general ways how to improve this (not assuming disabling the WAL)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @tomas-bartalos for the answer!

We found another issue, that was the **real cause of our problem - properties of Azure Gen2 Storage (with hierarchical namespace enabled)**. It seems Azure Gen2 is **slow when listing** a lot of files. We tried to open the streaming checkpoint directory using the Azure Explorer and it took about 20 seconds (similar to the `walCommit` time). We switched to the Azure Blob Storage and the problem was gone. We haven't done anything with the `crc` files (tomas's answer) so we concluded that te **storage mode was the main issue.**

Answer (score 3):

I've wrote you via Slack, but I will share the answer also here.

I’ve experienced same behavior, the reason was leak of hidden crc files in checkpoint/offsets directory.  It is a hadoop rename bug and is workarounded in Spark 2.4.4.

Link to [Spark JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28025)

If following find command executed in checkpoint directory returns number > ~1000, you're affected by this bug:

```
find . -name "*.crc" | wc -l
```

Workaround for Spark < 2.4.4 is to disable creating crc files (suggested in JIRA comments) :

```
--conf spark.hadoop.spark.sql.streaming.checkpointFileManagerClass=org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileSystemBasedCheckpointFileManager --conf spark.hadoop.fs.file.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem
```